# Confidentiality Agreement - Costs of the Company

Tags: non-disclosure-agreement

My confidentiality agreement covers costs of the company as confidential information. Would that normally include my own salary? Are there any guidelines on this?

> (A) Confidential Information means the confidential information of the 
>   Company, or any Group Company [...] including, without limitation, Trade 
>   Secrets, [...], prices, costs, business affairs [...].

Comment: If you aren't sure what is covered, why don't you ask the person who is asking you to sign the confidentiality agreement?

Comment: It's prohibited by law to forbid employees discussing their salary. References: [Ref1](https://www.lexisnexis.com/legalnewsroom/labor-employment/b/labor-employment-top-blogs/archive/2013/02/21/you-have-the-right-to-discuss-salary-with-coworkers.aspx),  [Ref2](https://www.insperity.com/blog/what-you-can-and-cant-do-when-employees-discuss-wages/)

Comment: @Y12K .. there was no mention of what country the OP is in, was there?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  They can only recover damages suffered from your disclosure.  They are going to be hard pressed to show any damages that would result from your sharing and unverified rate of pay.  Even if you gave them a paycheck stub that showed it, they still have to show that your sharing the information caused them damage to their business.

Comment: There may be regulations in your country explicitly allowing you to discuss you salary or even make that NDA void, because it is quite broad. Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: And trust me, people get fired for talking about salary even where it is illegal because they can always find a different reason to fire you , or in the US simply cite no reason at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "... including, **without** limitation, Trade Secrets, [...], prices, **costs**, **business affairs** [...]."
>
> "Q: Would that **normally** include my own salary?".

Normally, it would not.

In this case you've agreed to no limitations, if costs aren't your pay then business affairs would be; don't try to limit the scope.

This is why you ask for huge compensation for signing such an agreement. A reputable company wouldn't impose too restrictive an agreement unless they actually made something that is secret or highly competitive and subject to theft (unpatentable); they would be happy to pay a premium rate.

Last time I was asked to sign an agreement which listed many conditions and a broadly worded clause to not work for any competitors I was asking for double what was initially discussed - worked there almost a week, well worth it.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that include my own salary?

Although I am doing an educated guess, I think that your NDA mentions "prices, costs, business affairs,..." to refer about the prices and costs of your **products and services**, as well as the **business partners and customers** your company may have.

This includes, but may not be limited to, the price you charge to each client, the internal costs and prices of the materials you use or the products you create, the margin of profit you are obtaining, etc.

This has no reason why to include your salary, as you are no product or service of the company (technically you are an asset, but still a Human Being after all).

Mentioning your salary, although not recommended, is sometimes required when applying to jobs (specially in the application forms one may fill), so it is a common or at least not rare question to be asked.